# Adapt div to image size and proportion, constrained by maximum dimensions

Tags: css

I have some images in divs.

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x400">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
</div>
```

I can't find the combination of CSS that fulfils all 3 conditions:

- Maximum length of any dimension: 5em
- Minimum length of at least 1 dimension: 5em (i.e. either height or width should be 5em) (this is where I think I may need javascript for the boolean OR)
- div to completely enclose the img with no excess space (so, the div should have the same aspect ratio as the img)

I'm trying to do the CSS sizing stuff on the divs and then just set the image to `width: 100%, height: auto`, because I do other sizing functionality on the divs too (resize, move, etc).

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1zvq1rg6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: inline-block` for your `div`s as you are trying to modify the default display of a `div` here (size adapting to content).

For the image maximum width/height, the OR you are describing here can be written with `max-height` and `max-width`.

Then, if you want no space in your `div`, just set the `padding` to `0`.

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
.container > img {
  max-width: 5em;
  max-height: 5em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a1bec8zd